# AIR: Security Sandbox Violation when using remote images

Tags: apache-flex, security, air

*The code below is simplified for example*

I'm developing an AIR application (using Flex) which loads several of its images from a remote web server.  The images display fine, however, whenever I'm manipulating the containers which hold the remotely-loaded images, I get errors in my console:

```
*** Security Sandbox Violation ***
SecurityDomain 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif' tried to access incompatible context 'app:/sandbox_test.swf'
```

The images don't seem to be affected, but I don't like having errors displayed that I don't understand.  Here's a sample app that exemplifies the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:WindowedApplication width="500" height="500" xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
    <mx:HDividedBox width="100%" height="300" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0" backgroundColor="#000000" liveDragging="true">
        <mx:Image source="http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png"/>
        <mx:Image source="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif"/>
    </mx:HDividedBox>
</mx:WindowedApplication>
```

If you drag using the dragger on the HDividedBox, the security error appears.

I've looked at some of the Security class / security sandbox stuff for AIR, but by default AIR should have access to networked resources (which is why the images load I think).  Using Security.allowDomain("www.google.com") isn't an option in AIR - it just throws a SecurityError.

Does anyone know what's causing it, or how to fix it?  (Or maybe it's just a Flex/AIR bug?).

Also - does anyone know if there's a way to break when the error happens, so I can trace it to the root action causing it?

Comment: Have you used the debugger to figure out when the security error actually fires off? Is it during the drawing stage?

Comment: The debugger doesn't actually break when the errors fire, they just print to the console.  It's unclear how I can trace them to their source

Answer (score 3):

This security sandbox issue is specific to dragging UIComponents that have Image components in them. The Image components reference external images. I've looked everywhere and every post I run into the thread ends unanswered, which typically means its a bug.

My bootleg workaround? After the image has downloaded to the Image component, cache it as a bitmap and reassign the Image components source to the Bitmap. This fixed the issue for me:

```
private function authorImageLoadComplete(event:Event):void {
    var bp:Bitmap = dupeImage(authorImage);
    authorImage.source=bp;

}

private function dupeImage(source:Image):Bitmap {
    var data:BitmapData = Bitmap(source.content).bitmapData;
    var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(data);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Then your image tag in your UIComponent:

```
<mx:Image id="authorImage" complete="authorImageLoadComplete(event)"></mx:Image>
```

Best of luck guys

Answer (score 1):

For Flex 4, try setting the top level **WindowedApplication**'s **useNativeDragManager** property to false, as documented here: http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_How_do_you_make_a_Spark_custom_itemRenderer_with_a-16532.html

Answer (score 0):

Do this images show up when you aren't running in Debug? The problem is that the domain doesn't have a crossdomain.xml file setup to allow for images in Flash.

http://www.google.com/crossdomain.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="by-content-type" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

You should probably just grab the images and place them in your application's assets, or on a domain you control and can properly add a crossdomain.xml that would allow for the content. Security.allowDomain isn't going to have the affect you are looking for. [This article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/fplayer9_security.html) has the best explanation of crossdomain security I have read.

**See ryanstewart's comment below. The above is hogwash for an AIR app.**

Comment: That shouldn't matter with AIR. When you're on the desktop you are following a different set of rules. 

@Chris, is your app called sandbox_test? Is that why the app:/sandbox_test.swf file is referenced?

Comment: Yeah - the test app I made is called sandbox_test, just to make sure the problem wasn't something obscure with my real app.